# How execute function at 20 November 2017 15:53 [node-cron]

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I want execute a function at 20 November 2017 at 15:53 with node-cron so I do this:

```
    var task = cron.schedule('00 53 15 20 11 *', function() {
console.log("HELLO");               


            }, false);

            task.start();
```

The task is not execute because I think that I'm wronging put the date so I don't read the "HELLO" print. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run your code by using `cron.schedule('1 53 15 20 11 *', cb)`